# Tkinter access Canvas Objects created by Loop outside the loop

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to manipulate some Canvas objects created by a loop on the Tkinter Canvas. Unfortunately I cannot access the the coordinates of these rectangles outside the loop, only one of them. How can I access all of the rectangles created by the loop outside the loop to get their coordinates, as well as manipulate them? This question might not make sense so please ask me if you don't understand and I will try to explain it better. Thanks!

```
    for y in range(2):
        for x in range(2):
            x1 = x*230
            y1 = y*230
            height = x1 + 200
            width = y1 + 200
            music_catalog_rect = canvas.create_rectangle((x1, y1, height, width), fill='red')
            canvas.move(music_catalog_rect, 180, 20)
```

Comment: You would need to store each value of `music_catalog_rect` in some container that exists outside of the loop: perhaps append them to a list, perhaps store them in a dict keyed by `(x, y)`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I tried to append them to a list but then didn't know how to access them in order to manipulate them. For example, when I appended them, I got a list of values (9,10,11,12).

Comment: You would pass one of those values as a parameter to relevant Canvas methods - `canvas.move()` for example.  Quite possibly you would loop over the list and call such a method on each of the values in turn.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the items in some sort of data structure. You can then iterate over the structure to pick out specific values or iterate over all of the values.

For example, you might store them in a list:

```
rects = []
for y in range(2):
    for x in range(2):
        ...
        item = canvas.create_rectangle(...)
        rects.append(item)
        ...
```

This allows you to easily iterate over all of the items:

```
for item in rects:
    canvas.move(item, ...)
```

If keeping  the x,y data is important, you can use the x,y as a key to a dictionary:

```
rects = {}
for y in range(2):
    for x in range(2):
        ...
        item = canvas.create_rectangle(...)
        rects[(x,y)] = item
        ...
```

Then later, you do something like the following:

```
canvas.move(rects[(3,4)], ...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution works perfectly.

Comment: I actually want to ask one more question while on the topic, I tried canvas.move(rects[(3,4)], ...) but it returned TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple. What is the solution to this?

Comment: @AliKesserwani: if you are getting a "list indices" error, then you've defined `rects` as a llist rather than dictionary.